# How to make django all urls be to level slug?

Tags: python, django

How to make django all urls to be top level slug?
Top level slug I mean that all urls has unique slug example:

```
example.com/articles
example.com/article-1
example.com/article-2
example.com/article-3
example.com/reviews
example.com/reviews-1
example.com/reviews-2
but not:
example.com/articles/article-1
example.com/articles/article-2
example.com/articles/article-3
example.com/reviews/reviews-1
example.com/reviews/reviews-2
```

I have a lot of apps like articles, reviews, and other custom pages.

So, what you think about this aproach that I create app with model like this:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

and then I will use it in my articles model like this:

```
from links.models import Link

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    slug = models.OneToOneField(
        Link,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    body = models.TextField()
```

.

```
from links.models import Link

class Review(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    slug = models.OneToOneField(
        Link,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    review = models.TextField()
```

and then I will have only one url field in my mane urls.py file:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)', views.link, name='link'),
```

And now how I should filter data where I want to return article or review?

Like this or maybe there exists better solution?

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from .models import Link
from articles.models import Article
from review.models import Review

def link(request, link):
    link = Link.objects.get(link=link)
    if Article.objects.filter(slug=Link).exists():
        link = link.slug
        return HttpResponseRedirect(link)

    if Review.objects.filter(slug=Link).exists():
        link = link.slug
        return HttpResponseRedirect(link)

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

I need that for google because if I decide one day to change /articles to /blog then I will break hundreds of urls in google search.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is almost perfect. Only changes I recommend:

1) There doesn't seem to be need for a `Link` model. You `slug` can be a `CharField` inside the `Article` model itself

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
```

2) Reviews belong to articles. So instead of `Review` having a `ForeignKey` to this `Link` object which should no longer exist, it should have a `ForeignKey` to `Article`

Comment: But how I check if slug is unique? For example if i create blog post example.com/google-review and later i create review with slug google-review which link should be example.com/google-review Reviews is different app with different model.

Comment: You can constrain this in the model itself. See updated answer

Comment: class BaseContent(models.Model):
 slug = models.SlugField()

 class Meta:
  abstract = True 


I decided to create base class which are inherited by all models.

But now I don't know how to create views for each app. Because before each app had url with a view.
I need for example two views for two different apps. Each app stores different information and has different templates. How should I make that entered url triggers correct view?

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py file where you have registered all urls (ideally in same directory as settings.py) remove the prefix `articles/`

Something like

```
path('', include('articles.urls'))
```